# Azure CDN fetch data from backend

Tags: azure, nginx, redirect, backend, azure-cdn

I've setup an Azure CDN for our website. Our devs, however, want to load the index.html from a backend nginx server. Is there any way to keep the Azure CDN but dynamically load the index.html from the backend? An URL redirect is not an option, as we do not want the URL to change (still want domain.com and not api.domain.com/website).

URL in CDN: domain.com
URL for NginX server: api.domain.com/website/index.html

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

From the ask it looks like you want to serve index.html for domain.com. To achieve this, you don't need to deploy an alternative LB. Try setting the root directory to the location directives as shown below,
Ex: path to your project directory where index.html is located,

```
root /home/project/apps/stackoverflow;
index.html;
```